# Analogue to lxml's tostring(method='text') to return xml without text content?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Is there an analogue to `lxml`'s `etree.tostring(..., method='text')` that will return the XML document structure/nodes but remove the textual content within those nodes? I'm looking to quickly obtain the hierarchy of a document for review purposes without any of the contents itself. Removing attributes would be beneficial too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.iterwalk()` method to generate events for elements, then print out the structure yourself:

```
indent = []
for action, elem in etree.iterwalk(root, events=('start', 'end')):
    if action == 'start':
        print '{}<{}{}>'.format(''.join(indent), elem.tag, '/' if not len(elem) else '')
        indent.append('  ')
    else:
        indent.pop()
        if len(elem):
            print '{}</{}>'.format(''.join(indent), elem.tag)
```

This uses two-space indents to convey structure, but you can adjust that easily.

Example output:

```
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar/>
    <bar/>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar/>
  </foo>
  <foo/>
</root>
```

Comment: Great solution, chosen because it's succinct and python/lxml-only.

Answer (score 1):

You could use XSLT to copy all the nodes, but remove the attributes and text:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

content = '''\
<root>
<foo col1="a1">
    Remove
    <bar col7="A"/>this
    <bar col7="A1"/>text
</foo>
<foo col1="b1">
    <bar col7="B"/>
</foo>
<foo col1="c2">
</foo>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(content)
xslt = '''\
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>


<!-- Copy everything -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- To remove attributes or nodes, simply write a matching template that
     doesn't do anything. Therefore, it is removed -->
<xsl:template match="text()"/>  <!-- Remove text -->
<xsl:template match="@*"/>      <!-- Remove all attributes -->
    </xsl:stylesheet>
'''
xslt_doc = ET.fromstring(xslt)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt_doc)
tree = transform(root)

print(ET.tostring(tree))
```

yields

```
<root><foo><bar/><bar/></foo><foo><bar/></foo><foo/></root>
```

The XSLT was derived from [this](http://openwritings.net/public/xslt/remove-attributes-or-and-nodes).

Or, for pretty printing:

```
print(ET.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

yields

```
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar/>
    <bar/>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar/>
  </foo>
  <foo/>
</root>
```

Comment: Another great solution, though a little more verbose than the selected solution due to it's dependency on XSL.